# inject multiples collections into a view(template) BackboneJS

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I wonder if possible to pass multiple collections into a view once fetched, something like:

```
 Collection1 = new Collections.Collection();
 Collection1.fetch({
    success: function (collection) {
        //save it somewhere 
    }
 });

 Collection2 = new Collections.Collection();
 Collection2.fetch({
    success: function (collection) {
        //save it somewhere 
    }
 });
```

So once they are loaded... render my view (which also, Idk how to wait until both are fetched, so any help would be appreciated).

```
var template = _.template( $('#myTemplate').html(), { col1: collection1, col2 : collection2 } ) ;
```

Is this posible?, if not, what could I do if I need to access to different collections values into a template?

Thanks a ton in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if your template is ready to work with `col1` and `col2`, load both collections in the view, and setup event listeners so you re-render when any of them is ready:

```
var MyDoubleColView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    this.firstCollection = new Collections.Collection();
    this.secondCollection = new Collections.Collection();
    this.listenTo(this.firstCollection, "reset", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.secondCollection, "reset", this.render);

   this.firstCollection.fetch({reset:true});
   this.secondCollection.fetch({reset:true});
  },
  render: function(){
    var template = _.template( $('#myTemplate').html(), 
      { col1: this.firstCollection.toJSON(), col2 : this.secondCollection.toJSON() }) ;
  }
});
```

This will cause your view to re-render when any of the collections is hydrated from the server. I've used the `reset` event but you can use any other of the collection server-related events, like `sync`.

Have your template be ready for having an empty collection and you'll be good to go. :)

Comment: it worked like charm, you are a good man, CharlieBrown! thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

Backbone `.fetch` return a promise object, you can use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when(firstCollection.fetch(), secondCollection.fetch()).then(function () {
    //both are fetched
});
```